# Regex: retrieve codec format

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I receive text as below based on input file. How can I retrieve the Highlighted text using regex.

1)Video: h264 (High) (**avc1** / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 452x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 113:90], 297 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

2)Audio: aac (LC) (**mp4a** / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 76 kb/s (default)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aS3uH9/1 mihgt work, but it would help to know what flavor of regex

Answer (score 1):

If you alow lookaheads and lookbehinds, you could find it this way:

```
(?<=\)\s\().+(?=\s\/)
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/jT7gG3/1

Comment: That works perfectly for finding the formats in the string but you'd need to enclose the .+ in brackets if he wanted to be able to capture the format for later use. (Edit: I think you ended up doing the same thing as I did when I was trying something on regex101; it automatically inserts a closing bracket as soon as you type an opening one, so it looks like you did have brackets there and they just ended up out of place)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way, assuming the format is always in the second set of brackets, would be

```
/\(.*\)\s\((.*)\s\/
```

That'll match as a group anything preceding a space followed by a forward slash in the second bracketed section.